# Dates format in R: 3/31/2016 io 03/31/2016

Tags: r, date, format, as.date

Is there a way to have the dates in R as 3/31/2016 (not showing 03 for the month)?

Right now my code is:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-1-1"), as.Date("2016-10-1"), by="3 months") -1
dates <- format(dates, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
```

But the outcome is

```
[1] "12/31/1999" "03/31/2000" "06/30/2000" "09/30/2000"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub`, match the pattern of '0' at the start (`^`) of the string and replace it with blanks (`""`).

```
dates1 <- sub("^0", "", dates)
head(dates1)
#[1] "12/31/1999" "3/31/2000"  "6/30/2000"  "9/30/2000"  "12/31/2000" "3/31/2001"
```

NOTE: It is not clear why the standard format is not needed.

Comment: great one more time!

I need this new format to match a format from a csv file I'm importing and don't want to overwrite.

Comment: That won't create single digit days.  Try eg March 2nd.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  I thought about the days, but it seems like the OP specified about the months.  If we need the single digit days as well `sub("^0(.{2})0?", "\\1", c(dates[1:3], "03/02/2000"))
#[1] "12/31/1999" "3/31/2000"  "6/30/2000"  "3/2/2000"`